# JavaScript: Recursive function fails to handle Promises correctly

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I'm writint a simple game in Node. Player makes a move, which is issued as a promise. Next the move is checked for legality:

1. If legal - great, execute the next ".then"
2. If not - call the same function recursively to get a new move

What works: I manage to break out of the promises chain using "reject" + "catch" and recursively call the function.

What doesn't work: when `_makeMove` is called the second time, it's supposed to ask the player for a new move, pausing until they reply. What actually happens is the function just runs away to Step 3, *not waiting for the player's entry*.

I'm taking input through terminal, and the window is still at "please enter: ", but the code already ran away.. (ultimately hitting an "undefined" error, which is natural, as the player hasn't had a chance to enter a new move).

Code (simplified):

```
const _makeMove = (activePlayer) => {

    //player makes a move, which is returned as a promise
    activePlayer.proposeMove()

      //Step 1 - check if legal
      .then(proposedMove => {
        if (!gameBoard.checkLegal(proposedMove)) {
          return Promise.reject("bad entry");
        }
        return proposedMove;
      })

      //Step 2 - record the move
      .then(proposedMove => {
        activePlayer.recordMove(proposedMove);
        return proposedMove;
      }) //unless step 1 fails...
      .catch(err => {
        console.log('oops bad entry!')
        //in which case let's ask the player to move again...
        //by calling the function RECURSIVELY
        _makeMove(activePlayer);
      })

      //Step 3 - game goes on...
      .then(proposedMove => {
        //more stuff
      })
  }
```

I'm completely puzzled. Why is the recursive call not working as expected?

Comment: You *probably* don't need promises for this, as they're designed for asynchronous programming. You know your program best, though

Comment: You might consider whether your catch block needs to _return_ _makeMove instead of just invoking it.

Answer (score 1):

In order for your promise chain to take the value from `_makeMove`, you have to **return the result of `_makeMove`**. Don't worry about the value being a promise; it will be automatically resolved before the next `then` in the chain is invoked.

```
      .catch(err => {
        console.log('oops bad entry!')
        return _makeMove(activePlayer);
        //  ^ return here
      })
```

However, the `_makeMove` result here will complete before the `then` is returned, which would likely make your `recordMove` call return twice. You might need to **split into `_makeMove` and `_recordMove` functions** so the recursive call to `_makeMove` would not record a move.

Though you could theoretically run out of stack, for a reasonable number of move attempts it wouldn't affect the correctness. The two errors above would.

Comment: Hey - thanks for the comment. So unfortunately adding return does nothing. I forgot to mention in original post that I tried it too. The problem isn't in the original stack, it's in the 2nd stack (called recursively), where the program doesn't wait for input and just runs past. At least that's my interpretation. What am I missing?

Comment: @ilmoi It's hard to say what else is missing without code we can run, and your original question doesn't include `proposeMove` or other implementations that might interact. Can you simplify your code into the shortest form that could reproduce your problem? Promises are asynchronous, so what you described is still consistent with missing `return`: Your recursive call would ask for input, but because there's no `return` your original step 2 would proceed. Ultimately, though, without being able to run your code, all I can do is guess based on how Promises are supposed to work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you should use recursive call here. And if you get a very dump player, you could reach a Stack Overflow error ;)

```js
const _makeMove = async (activePlayer) => {
  let proposedMove = null;

  while (1) {
    proposedMove = await activePlayer.proposeMove();
    if (gameBoard.checkLegal(proposedMove)) {
       break;
    }
  }
  activePlayer.recordMove(proposedMove);
  // do more stuff
}
```

Comment: No, a recursive approach in asynchronous functions won't overflow the stack.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestions above. After tinkering, I ended up doing 2 things that solved it:

1. I rewrote my promise chain from a bunch of `.then` methods using `async/await`. This solved the original issue of the recursive call falling through to Step 3 and not pausing at Step 2 (which I still find magical..)
2. This however, created a new problem. Initially I chained a single `.catch` to the end of the `async` function, but that only triggered *once*. Ie 2nd, 3rd, 4th recursive calls would lead to `Unhandled exception` errors. So I instead placed all the code inside of a `try` block inside the function, and put a `catch` block *also inside the function*. This works beautifully

Final code:

```
const _makeMove = async (activePlayer) => {
    try {
      //Step 1 - take input
      const proposedMove = await activePlayer.proposeMove();

      //Step 2 - check if legal
      if (!gameBoard.checkLegal(proposedMove)) {
        throw new Error("bad entry");
      }

      //Step 3 - etc
      //Step 4 - etc
      //Step 5 - etc

    } catch (e) {
      console.log('oops bad entry!')
      console.log("how it works: type 2 numbers ONLY, each between 1 and 3 (no spaces), to signify your move")
      console.log("eg to place a mark into bottom left corner type 33. First cell = 11. Bang in the center = 22. You get it.")
      console.log('lets try again...')
      return _makeMove(activePlayer);
    }
  };
```